# Outlook 2003 not completely closing with Spambayes loaded

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

Does anyone know if there is a fix for Spambayes so that it will allow Outlook to close properly (and completely)? With Spambayes loaded, Outlook 2003 process never completely shuts down when I exit out, and I need to kill the process manually.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Please regard this [thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/spambayes-bugs/2007-July/004232.html) regarding this problem.
To summarize, it seems like Spambayes is not the only cause for such problems, although uninstalling it fixed the problem for some people. Other people had a problem with ActiveSync for the PDA, cell phone etc.
Still others have reported that's rather the spam filter that comes with outlook that's causing it to hang, and once turned off the problem was solved.

Please also have a look at this [web site](http://www.daveswebsite.com/software/olshutdown/) that sells a product named Shutdown Addin for $4.99. I quote from this site:

> Outlook is notorious for hanging
>   around in the background when a user
>   exits the application. The cause of
>   this is partly a random behavior of
>   Outlook itself and most often a user
>   installed addin that does not release
>   itself from Outlook correctly.
>   Typically, the solution is to
>   uninstall the offending addin.
>   However, if you really like an addin
>   and can't wait for the developer to
>   fix it or have no addin's installed
>   and Outlook STILL stays running the
>   background then you'll want to try
>   Shutdown Addin.